# Algebric expressions As a single fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus

2x/5 - x/4 
Can anyone find me the answer?
Question is Express this as asingle fraction

Answer (score 1):

For addition and subtraction, you must find a ***common denominator*** before doing anything else. Don't be distracted by the '$x$' term for the time being.

$$\frac{2x}{5} - \frac{x}{4} = (\frac{4}{4}*\frac{2x}{5}) - (\frac{5}{5}*\frac{x}{4}) = \frac{8x}{20} - \frac{5x}{20} = \frac{(8x - 5x)}{20} = \frac{3x}{20}$$

Comment: @Goodra suggested some edits to my answer, but I'm new to this site and I don't quite know how to accept those edits

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{2x}{5}-\frac{x}{4}=\frac{4\cdot2x}{4\cdot5}-\frac{5\cdot x}{5\cdot4}=\frac{8x}{20}-\frac{5x}{20}=\frac{8x-5x}{20}=\frac{3x}{20}$$